# PayPal - subscribe button with credit card

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using the PayPal subscribe button in my site.

Is it possible to allow user to subscribe (through the paypal subscribe button) with their credit card without having a paypal account?

I know that the donate button allows it.

any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, no.
However, in the US and UK you can sign up for PayPal 'Enhanced Recurring Payments' (US) or 'Premium Services' (UK) which allows you to do just that.

Here is the link to the sign-up page for the UK: https://www.paypal-business.co.uk/premiumservices/index.htm